# Multiple expects within scenario test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, integration-testing, scenarios

I have a scenario test:

```
scenario 'displays the form' do
  # Build the setup for user coming from an external site.
  expect(page).to have_selector('#braintree-dropin-frame', count: 1)

  # User reloads the page
  expect(page).to have_selector('#braintree-dropin-frame', count: 1)

  # User visits page from within the website.
  expect(page).to have_selector('#braintree-dropin-frame', count: 1)
end
```

First off, is this the proper usage of a scenario test? I'm essentially testing the same thing but in different scenarios. I feel like this should really be three separate scenario tests inside a context block. Am I misusing `scenario`?

Comment: you might want to add some more context, how is `page` set, for example?

Comment: `page` is just the html of the page. It's provided by Capybara I believe. My main concern with this test is that I'm running different scenarios within one scenario test. At the same time, I'm testing for the same thing, "Does #braintree-dropin-frame exist on the page?"

Comment: I don't understand how any of the three tests differ, aren't the testing the same thing on the same page?

Comment: If this isn't one user flow then they should be separate features/scenarios.  Additionally since you're using a CSS selector here you probably want to be using `have_css` rather than `have_selector` here

Comment: @Tom, that's what I'm looking for. Post as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't one user flow then they should be separate features/scenarios.  You also need to be careful when setting expectations for the same selector multiple times in a test that you've checked it has gone away between (if you are checking it reappears again), otherwise you can end up with tests passing when they shouldn't due to timing and asynchronous behavior issues.

Additionally - since you're checking for a CSS selector you probably want to be using `have_css` rather than `have_selector` since it reads nicer and will mean the tests keep working if the default selector type is ever changed from :css